# paraview/VTK display of a box

Tags: paraview

I am using paraview (VTK) for the display of an unstructured mesh. I am aware that once in Paraview, I can select sources->alphabetical and have the box (or disk) displayed. However, I would like to specify the x,y,z location of the box inside the vtk file I use (for display of unstrcutured/Finite element mesh). WOuld that be possible? if so how?

thanks

Comment: Not sure to follow: you want to display only the bounding box of your data ?

Comment: no, I would like to display my data (a finite element mesh, i/e. unstructured mesh), but at certain location (where cracking takes place), I would like to display an oriented disk to show that something is happening at this particular location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (at least should not) mix your data with this extra info in the same mesh. So the way to do that is to use [multiblock](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/understandingData.html?highlight=multiblock#multiblock-dataset) (here for [VTK doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMultiBlockDataSet.html) ), where one leaf of the MultiBlock is your unstructured mesh and others are polydatas around your zone of interest.

Comment: Agree, this would be sort of a separate "layer", the point is given that those disks will be plotted through multiblock, is there a way around defining each one of them through polydata (about 16 vertices and 11 polygons) to be transformed (translation and scaling for each one)? (disclaimer, I am relatively new to paraview)

Comment: You cannot directly transform a part of a multiblock, you need to extract a block it before, then apply the transform.